# Prove an equality using MVT

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Prove that there exists $\epsilon \in (a, b)$, $b>a>0$, such that the equality $ae^b-be^a=(1-\epsilon)e^\epsilon(a-b)$ holds.

My approach:
Let $f(x)=xe^{u(x)}$. $f'(x)=e^u(1+xu'(x)).$ By MVT, there exists $\epsilon \in (a, b)$, $b>a>0$ such that $f'(\epsilon)=f(b)-f(a)/b-a=be^{u(b)}-ae^{u(a)}/b-a=ae^{u(a)}-be^{u(b)}/a-b$. i.e.$ae^{u(a)}-be^{u(b)}=f'(\epsilon)(a-b)$

I am stuck at this step. I cannot figure out what $u(x)$ should I set such that making this equality holds. Any ideas or thoughts? I know $u(a)=b$, $u(b)=a$ and $f'(\epsilon)=(1-\epsilon)e^\epsilon$. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I think $u(x)=b+a-x$ would do.

Comment: But $f′(\epsilon)=(1−\epsilon)e^\epsilon$ does not satisfy